# Silence volume control rocker click

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I have an FonePad X, android 4.4.2.  When I go to bed at night I turn down all my volumes.  But the volume control rocker emits a beep when I use it to turn down the volumes.  I don't need a notification that I'm turning down the volume, and I'm trying to be quiet so as to not awaken my sleeping partner.  I find this annoying.

Is this volume control notification sound silence-able?

Comment: Is the device rooted? Gravitybox can do this easily. No root needed: [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) combined with [AutoInput](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autoinput&hl=en) can also do the job. There is more. You can create  a shortcut on home screen that will decrease all the volume so you don't even have to touch the volume rockers, let alone disturb anyone in vicinity.

Comment: No, I'm not rooted, and I can't root as I use my phone for work related stuff (calendar things) and they prohibit rooting.  My latest trick is to install a white noise app and start that app before I enter the bedroom.  And I now go to bed first, so it becomes a moot issue.